# Node.js Error "Cannot switch to old mode now." with MySQL NPM

Tags: mysql, node.js

Node.js throws the below error when issuing a query via the [mysql npm](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql).

```
_stream_readable.js:664
throw new Error('Cannot switch to old mode now.');

Error: Cannot switch to old mode now.
at emitDataEvents (_stream_readable.js:664:11)
at Socket.Readable.resume (_stream_readable.js:649:3)
```

Sample code which throws this error:

```
query  = mysqlCLI.query( 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = 1' );
results = [];

mysqlCLI.resume();

query

  .on( 'error', function ( err ) {

    console.log( 'Bad Things: ', err );

  })

  .on( 'result', function ( row ) {

      results.push( row );

  })

  .on( 'end', function (){

    mysqlCLI.pause();

    dataHandler( results );

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This took quite a bit of troubleshooting, but the ultimate fix for this was to remove both `mysqlCLI.pause();` and `mysqlCLI.resume();`. The odd thing about this problem was that the code executed fine on Windows Server 2003 but once I cloned via Git it broke under CentOS 5.9 (RHEL).